# Error when reading control container:Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException

Tags: mysql, windows-7, azure, appfabric

I am trying to follow the instructions for the Windows Azure Mysql PHP solution Accelerator ( http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/winazuremysqlphp ) and I get the following error in the Fabric UI and Mysql doesn't start. http://www.pastie.org/1297146

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your diagnostics connection string is bogus... check to make sure it's pointing to a valid account and that the key is correct.  Or just disable diagnostics by commenting out DiagnosticMonitor.Start(...) (should be in WorkerRole.cs).